# How to fix "stackoverflowexception occured in mscorlib.dll" when comparing 2 LINQ list?

Tags: c#, linq, dynamics-crm-2011

I have 2 LINQ list (defined as IQueryable). These contain just usernames from 2 different systems. 1st list is from our ActiveDirectory server (source is a SQL Server DB) and the 2nd one is from a vendor application (source is built-in contacts entity in Microsoft CRM 2011).

The 1st list has about 36K records while the 2nd one has about 43K. Each record ha a max of 8bytes/characters.

I tried using the Except function [click here for MS page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397894.aspx) and when I try iterate through the result, I am getting this error message:

```
unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occured in mscorlib.dll
```

Here's the code I'm running

```
        ADUserDataDAO _aduserDataDAO = new ADUserDataDAO();
        IQueryable<String> _adUserDatas = _aduserDataDAO.getADUserData();
        //int ctr = 0;
        //foreach (var record in _adUserDatas) { ++ctr; Console.WriteLine("username :\t{0}", _record); }
        //Console.WriteLine("total records: \t{0}", ctr);

        ContactsDAO _contactsDAO = new ContactsDAO();
        IQueryable<String> _contacts = _contactsDAO.GetContacts();
        //int ctr = 0;
        //foreach (var _record in _contacts) { ++ctr; Console.WriteLine("username :\t{0}", _record); }
        //Console.WriteLine("total records: \t{0}", ctr);

        IQueryable<String> _inADUserDatas = _adUserDatas.Except(_contacts);
        int ctr = 0;
        foreach (var _record in _inADUserDatas) { ++ctr; Console.WriteLine("username :\t{0}", _record); }
        Console.WriteLine("total records: \t{0}", ctr);
```

I can iterate through each list using the code above (see commented code) so I know I'm getting something from the get functions.

Any ideas what could be wrong? thanks a lot

Comment: I have you tried calling `ToList` on the `IQueryable` interface, and then comparing the lists instead of through the `IQueryable` interface?

Comment: Cool will add my comment as an answer, so further users can see what worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `ToList()` on the `IQueryable` interface, and then compare the lists instead of comparing them through the `IQueryable` interface